# Is it a bad idea to run OpenVPN and a Tor relay on the same VPS?

Tags: relays, exit-relays, openvpn

> 1. Get a separate IP for the node. Do not route your own traffic via this IP
>      While it may be tempting to mix in your traffic with your node's exit traffic 
>      for cover, this is best avoided. Having a separate IP allows your ISP to more   easily recognize that abuse complaints and DMCA notices can be forwarded to you  to be quickly responded to with a boilerplate response, as opposed to cutting   off your Internet access or providing your personal information to the copyright  cartels.

I know that [this is the recommendation for an exit node](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/tips-running-exit-node-minimal-harassment), but can I run OpenVPN and a Tor relay on the same machine, using the same IP address? I can't see why not, as Tor relays do not route traffic to the outside world, but I thought I'd ask, just to make sure.

Comment: I'm confused by this question. Is OP running a middle or exit relay? The statement "Tor relays do not route traffic to the outside world" implies middle, but the blog quote implies exit. Also, is OP running an OpenVPN server, or a client? In either case, correct routing and firewall rules on this VPS would be essential.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. There is no issue with that.

There are some considerations, the same as running a relay on your home connection: Some websites block access from *all* Tor relays, exit or not. Now that your IP and hostname are listed on public web pages, you may get more 'traffic' probing for vulnerabilities.